# PayPal pending payments are not supported

Tags: php, android, paypal, braintree

if i pay to payment using **paypal braintree** then get error in result like 
Braintree\Result\Error[errors=,....

**message=PayPal pending payments are not supported**

how can i resolve?

Comment: There may be a few ways to solve this, but I think it relies heavily on your PayPal sandbox settings. I'd reach out to [Braintree's Support Team](https://help.braintreepayments.com) to see what insight they may have into this. These authorization errors are fairly account-specific.